# FreeRTOS Timer Use

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, arduino-nano

I use Timer1 on an UNO to generate a 38KHZ signal for IR communications. It all works as expected.

BUT, I need to convert the code to run as a task under FreeRTOS, and can't seem to find any details about which HW timers are available for the UNO or MEGA.

Also, as long as I'm asking about FreeRTOS, is it reliable for the timer tick to be changed from the 15ms that I think is standard to something faster?

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I found my own answer by looking into the FreeRTOS source code.

FreeRTOS uses timer0, timer1, timer2 and timer3 according to the source code. I assume that it uses the timers as required based on CPU type and capability.